# Unsetting event handling after Ajax while using jQuery on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, event-handling

The JS code below works fine if loaded via a normal page load. However, if the page containing this code is refreshed via Ajax, then the `click` is registered multiple times, one for each time the page is refreshed via Ajax. You can tell this by either the number of times the word "Saved" is printed or by the number of times the `console.log` message "#SavedBtn clicked" appears.

Is there some way to unset the click handler when the page is loaded via Ajax?

HTML:

```
<button type='button' id='saveBtn'></button>
```

JS:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#saveBtn', function(){
    var t='<span class="savedSpan">Saved</span>';
    $(this).after(t);
    console.log('#saveBtn clicked');
    $('.savedSpan').animate({
        color: "#FFF4D2"
        }, 1000).fadeOut();                           
});
```

Comment: Do you really need to use event delegation for this event? there's only one `saveBtn` (if there's more than one, you're doing it wrong.) If you bound it directly, you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: I'm using `on()`/event delegation because the `saveBtn` is not in the DOM when the page loads. Also, its just a simple demonstration. Of course the actual use case is more complicated.

Comment: But it is in the dom when you load the ajax, right? and the ajax runs the code?

Comment: @Kevin B: what do you mean with event delegation not necessary because there is only one `saveBtn`?. You normally use this approach to bind an event to future elements that could be created matching provided selector.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I find it very unlikely that the `saveBtn` isn't being re-created with each ajax request, which would mean he could actually bind directly to it even though it is dynamic because the code is running every time it is created.

Comment: the `saveBtn` is in a popover which is dynamically created by the user at some point **after** the page loads.

Comment: @timpeterson is that popover also what is executing the above code? If not, what is executing the above code? and why isnt' the above code in a more global script so that it doesn't execute more than once?

Comment: no, i'm just using twitter bootstrap popover and adding in custom HTML which is actionable when the popover appears. Seemed easier than extending the plugin.

Comment: I don't think the difference between delegation and direct binding matters for his problem. The real issue is why is the binding code being re-executed after the AJAX call?

Comment: well, the point i'm making (poorly i'll admit) is he should be doing either or, not both. Either use delegation and have it only execute once, or don't use event delegation.

Comment: @Barmar cause the binding code is in an external script that is loaded with the rest of the ajax-loaded HTML (DOM fragment). Like many scripts on my application, I don't need this particular binding code anywhere else in my application so that's why it's not part of DOM to begin with, i.e., the original normal page load.

Comment: jjnguy's solution below will solve your problem. I personally wouldn't do it that way, but there really aren't any drawbacks to it. An alternative would be to replace `document.body` with an element that gets replaced when the rest of the ajax-loaded html is updated.

Comment: @KevinB you have a good point and I generally follow that advice. In this case i'll just go with Jinguy's answer since it does provide a working solution and is helpful to know about, but point taken. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a call to [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) before calling [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This will remove the handler before adding another one.

The code might look like:

```
$(document.body).off('click', '#saveBtn');
$(document.body).on('click', '#saveBtn', function(){
    var t='<span class="savedSpan">Saved</span>';
    $(this).after(t);
    console.log('#saveBtn clicked');
    $('.savedSpan').animate({
        color: "#FFF4D2"
        }, 1000).fadeOut();                           
});
```